# Why should keys be hidden from an eavesdropper for a pseudorandom function?

Tags: keys, provable-security, pseudo-random-function

What advantage would knowing the key used for a given pseudorandom function give over having access to an oracle for that function $F_k(\cdot)$ and the actual key $k$ which will be used?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate of fkraiem's answer, the security property we want a pseudorandom function family $F$ to possess is (computational) indistinguishability from a random function.  That is, an adversary, given oracle access to *some* function $f: X \to Y$, should not be able to distinguish between the following two possibilities:

1. $f = F_k$ for some randomly chosen (secret) key $k$, or
2. $f$ is chosen uniformly at random from the entire set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$.

The key thing to realize is that the adversary is allowed to know how to compute $F_k(x)$ for any given key $k$ and input $x$.  Thus, if the adversary knew which key $k$ was *supposedly* used to be used to instantiate the oracle in case 1, they could simply pick an arbitrary input $x$, query the oracle for $f(x)$, and check if the result matches $F_k(x)$.  If $f$ really is $F_k$, the results will obviously always match; if $f$ is a random function, they will only do so with probability $1/|Y|$.

---

Ps. Since the function family $F$ is efficiently computable, and since we wish to show that *no* efficient adversary can distinguish a random instance of $F$ from a random function, it really makes no difference whether we explicitly grant the adversary knowledge of how to compute $F$ or not: among all the possible efficient adversaries, there will always be some that *just happen* to know how to correctly compute $F$.  Of course, there are also countless possible adversaries that compute $F$ wrong, and thus fail to distinguish between the two scenarios, but we're only concerned about the few that get it right.

Of course, for any given key $k$, there will also be some adversaries that can simply guess it correctly.  The difference is that the definition of $F$ is fixed, whereas in the indistinguishability game, $k$ is chosen at random every time the game is played.  So an adversary that correctly guesses the definition of $F$ will evaluate it correctly every time, whereas an adversary that correctly guesses $k$ in one round of the game will almost surely guess wrong on any other round.

Perhaps a clearer way to think about this is that, by allowing the adversary to be *any* efficient algorithm, and requiring our cryptosystem to be secure against *any* such adversary, we're basically allowing the adversary to know *any* information that can be encoded as a polynomial-time algorithm, and that is not explicitly randomized (and kept hidden from the adversary) as part of the game.  In particular, this implicitly embodies [Kerckhoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle): among the set of all possible adversaries, there are always some that know exactly how our cryptosystem works

Answer (score 2):

With $k$ the adversary can compute $F_k(x)$ for some $x$ using the evaluation algorithm, and compare it to the answer of its oracle on $x$.